# Embed additional information on a Blockchain Block

Tags: blockchain

I'm trying to define the implementation details of a potential Blockchain application.

Basically it would rely on Blockchain technology to record the fact that a transaction had happened between two parties (implementation understood), but there would be additional information relevant to that transaction that would also need to be associated with it (implementation not understood). Say, for example, in the form of a PDF.

Which, if any, is the right way to think about implementing this:

1. Attach / embed the PDF to the newly created 'block'
2. Link from the newly created 'block' to the PDF

The main requirement is that the existence of the information in PDF form (uploaded by one of the transaction participants) is persisted for as long as the 'block' exists.

Note: it does not necessarily need to be a PDF - just some kind of information stored external to the block itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can only embed 40 bytes into a transaction using `OP_RETURN` command: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_RETURN

What people usually do is embed `sha256` of the data for verification purposes.